# How do I correctly map a texture to a hexagon in LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have a script that renders a 2D hexagon-shaped grid of hexagon tiles.  The grid loads fine, but my textures are missing huge bits of color.  What is wrong with my code?  Have I mapped the coordinates incorrectly?

This is the texture image that I am loading:
[image]

This is how the texture appears in my game:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
public class LWJGLHelloWorld {

    public static int SCREEN_WIDTH;
    public static int SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    public static int WINDOW_WIDTH;
    public static int WINDOW_HEIGHT;
    public double WIDTH;
    public double HEIGHT;
    public ArrayList<Hexagon> hexagons = new ArrayList<Hexagon>();
    public ArrayList<String> resources = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Texture brick;
    public Texture stone;
    public Texture lumber;
    public Texture wool;
    public Texture wheat;
    public Texture wasteland;
    public int textureID;
    private float[][] textureCoords = { 
        {0.5f, 0.5f},
        {0.5f, 0.0f},
        {0.0f, 0.25f},
        {0.0f, 0.75f},
        {0.5f, 0.0f},
        {1.0f, 0.75f},
        {1.0f, 0.25f}
};
    private static enum State {
        INTRO, MAIN_MENU, GAME;
    }

    private State state = State.INTRO;

    public LWJGLHelloWorld(){

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        double SCREEN_WIDTH = screenSize.getWidth();
        double SCREEN_HEIGHT = screenSize.getHeight();
        double WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH * .85;
        double HEIGHT = SCREEN_HEIGHT * .85;

        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode((int)WIDTH, (int)HEIGHT));
            Display.setTitle("Hello, LWJGL!");;
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        resetResources();


        brick = loadTexture("brick");
        stone = loadTexture("stone");
        lumber = loadTexture("lumber");
        //Texture wheat = loadTexture("wheat");
        wool = loadTexture("wool");
        wasteland = loadTexture("wasteland");

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        int originX = (int)(Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth() / 2);
        int originY = (int)(Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight() / 2);
        int radius = (int)(HEIGHT * .1);
        int padding = (int)(HEIGHT * .005);

        findHexCoords(originX, originY, 5, radius, padding);

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
            checkInput();
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            for(int h = 0; h < hexagons.size(); h++){
                String rsrc = resources.get(h);
                switch(rsrc){
                case "brick":
                    brick.bind();
                    break;
                case "stone":
                    stone.bind();
                    break;
                case "lumber":
                    lumber.bind();
                    break;
                case "wheat":
                    //wheat.bind();
                    break;
                case "wool":
                    wool.bind();
                    break;
                case "wasteland":
                    wasteland.bind();
                    break;  
                }
                glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
                Hexagon hex = hexagons.get(h);
                for(int p = 0; p < hex.points.length; p++){
                    Point point = hex.points[p];
                    glVertex2f(point.x, point.y);
                    glTexCoord2f(textureCoords[p][0], textureCoords[p][0]);
                    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                }
                glEnd();
            }

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }

        Display.destroy();
    }

    private void bindTexture(String rsrc){

    }

    private void findHexCoords(int x, int y, int size, int radius, int padding) {

        Point origin = new Point(x, y);
        double ang30 = Math.toRadians(30);
        double xOff = Math.cos(ang30) * (radius + padding);
        double yOff = Math.sin(ang30) * (radius + padding);
        int half = size / 2;

        int i = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {

            int cols = size - Math.abs(row - half);

            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {

                int xLbl = row < half ? col - row : col - half;
                int yLbl = row - half;
                int centerX = (int) (origin.x + xOff * (col * 2 + 1 - cols));
                int centerY = (int) (origin.y + yOff * (row - half) * 3);

                Hexagon hex = new Hexagon(centerX, centerY, radius);
                System.out.println(centerX+","+centerY);
                hexagons.add(hex);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkInput(){
        switch(state){
        case INTRO:
            if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)){
                state = State.MAIN_MENU;
            }
            if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)){
                Display.destroy();
                System.exit(0);;
            }
            break;
        case GAME:
            if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_BACK)){
                state = State.MAIN_MENU;
            }
            break;
        case MAIN_MENU:
            if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RETURN)){
                state = State.GAME;
            }
            if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)){
                state = State.INTRO;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private Texture loadTexture(String key){
        try {
            return TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("img/" + key + ".png")));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LWJGLHelloWorld();

    }

    public void resetResources(){
        resources.clear();
        resources.add("Brick");
        resources.add("Brick");
        resources.add("Brick");
        resources.add("Wool");
        resources.add("Wool");
        resources.add("Wool");
        resources.add("Wool");
        resources.add("Lumber");
        resources.add("Lumber");
        resources.add("Lumber");
        resources.add("Lumber");
        resources.add("Stone");
        resources.add("Stone");
        resources.add("Stone");
        resources.add("Wheat");
        resources.add("Wheat");
        resources.add("Wheat");
        resources.add("Wheat");
        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        Collections.shuffle(resources, new Random(seed));
        int randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 19);
        resources.add(randomIndex, "Wasteland");
        for(int r = 0; r < resources.size(); r++){
            System.out.println(resources.get(r));
        }
    }

}
```

## Update

I assume this is happening because my texture coordinates are not correct because whenever I change them, the area of black in the textures changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your texture coordinates are indeed wrong. Since you're drawing a polygon as a whole, there isn't any vertex with texture coordinate [0.5, 0.5], which is center of a texture.

Try to use image bellow to determinate your texture coordinates properly. :)

[image]

Write down a texture coordinate for each vertex and put 'em in same order as you're drawing your vertices.

**EDIT:**

To be fair, you would be much better to draw those tiles as rectangles/quads and make 'em overlap a little bit. Your texture coordinates then would be {[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0]} assuming youre starting at bottom left corner and drawing clockwise. See image bellow.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Which coordinate do I start with and which direction do they go in?

Comment: Start with a coordinate for hex.points[0] and go from there. :) I can't really test it myself right now, but I bet it's going to be either top-middle or top-right vertex.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.  What should my textureCoords[][] array be?

Comment: It should probably start with top-middle coordinate, which is [0.5, 0] and go clockwise from there. Do you know order of points youre drawing your hexagon tile at ?

Comment: My guess is {[0.5, 1], [1, 0.75], [1, 0.25], [0.5, 0], [0, 25], [0.75]} or {[1, 0.75], [1, 0.25], [0.5, 0], [0, 25], [0.75], [0.5, 1]}. Im assuming you're drawing those hexagon points clockwise.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 Please see the last edit of my original answer. :)

Comment: glOrtho is set to have 0,0 be in the upper left corner.

Comment: glOrtho doesn't affect texture coordinates having [0, 0] at lower left corner. You should really draw those hexagons as quads overlapping each other. You'll save yourself a lot of trouble and performance. :)